# Низкий битрейт аудио на youtube, при загрузке через youtube-dl

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube

Я пытаюсь извлечь аудиофайл из видео на youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5r3uCKFAls) при помощи библиотеки youtube-dl. Проблема заключается в том, что youtube-dl утверждает, что максимальный битрейт этого аудио - 128kbps. Хотя на самом деле его битрейт 320kbps. Я также пробовал скачивать аудио с других видео, но  в любом случае оно не превышало 128kbps.

Что я должен сделать чтобы youtube-dl увидел реальный битрейт? Ниже код моих действий. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from youtube_dl import *
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5r3uCKFAls'
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    }],
}
with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

А вот что он показывает, когда я прошу узнать битрейт аудио:

```
with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    print(info_dict.get("abr", None))  # output: 128
```

Comment: «Хотя на самом деле его битрейт 320kbps» — откуда вы это узнали?

Comment: В заголовке написано) Я понимаю, что это может быть неправдой, но я пробовал десяток других видео; ютуб не даёт больше 128kbps. И еще загляните сюда (у чувака был подобная проблема с тем же видео, но он решил ее): https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/3586

Comment: Если бы в заголовке было написано 77777kbps, вы бы тоже поверили?) Заголовки не имеют абсолютно никакого отношения к реальным характеристикам аудиопотока. Впрочем, YouTube отдаёт Opus 160kbps, и youtube-dl может его скачать, но вот 320kbps вы уже ниоткуда не возьмёте, и по вашей ссылке написано то же самое.

Comment: Это печально, но это так. Спасибо, что избавили меня от лишних поисков